# show svg rendered percentage while loading with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, svg, progress-bar

I want help on showing percentage rendered svg, while page is being loaded with jquery. I have a huge svg animation to load with loading message showing up.

More details:

I've a svg animation file which takes huge time to load, so during that period of time, i want to deliver some welcome message to the visitor.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Can you supply more details

Comment: I've a svg animation file which takes huge time to load, so during that period of time, i want to deliver some welcome message to the visitor through jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using ajaxProgress Plugin http://www.kpozin.net/ajaxprogress

Thanks anyways.

Here's the code snippet:

```
    $.ajax("/myfile", {progress: function(jqXHR, progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            console.log("Loaded " + (Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100)) + "%");
        } else {
            console.log("Loading...");
        }
    }});
```